# Is it possible to convert a an EndNote Reference Style into a bst file?

Tags: bibliographies

I just started to use Latex in order to write my master thesis.
Right now I am stuck on implementing my own Bibliography style and I though might it be possible to transfer my bibliography style I designed for my ba thesis in Endnote to a bst file for Latex..

I am using `miktex` with `texmaker`and the bibpackage `natbib`.

cheers.

Comment: Maybe it's because I don't know if "Endnote" is a piece of software or a qualitative descriptor, but your question seems vague.  Could you edit to provide further elaboration on your goal?

Comment: There are tools like custombib, but getting *exactly* what you want might need quite a bit of effort and time.

Comment: Customizing a standard biblatex style might be easier, see https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber for a start.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: EndNote is a software for doing bibliographies in the Micro$oft World (MS Word etc.)

Comment: Thanks. I have used the custombib to create my own bst file but I am getting a few of errors which I am not able to solve with the help I have found so far so I might just settle for an existing style...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes 

My goal is to have a customized referencing style. I have used the make bst but i encountered problems while running it/ I was unhappy with the output
Thats why i was wondering if there is a possibiity to transfer the referencing style I defined in the program I previously used (endnote) into latex... 
But I guess that is even more complicated...